# SQL: View and table

Tags: sql, database, view, ibm-soliddb

If I create a view, is the view reflect physical table real time or it is just a materialized view and synchronize with physical table every n seconds/minutes. If I want to update something, may I update the materialized view, then would db synchronize the view and table?

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: I am using solid db. solid 7.

Answer (score 7):

The view reflects the table structure.  Any changes made to the tables data will be reflected in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may update data using views, changes will apply to the base table immediately. In fact views do not contain any data at all.

Comment: If one db operation update one view, the other db operation update the other view. If they are both updating same row in the physical table, will be a db conflict? Or the db management would serialize the operation?

Comment: It may depend on your database system, but generally first query will use row lock, and second will wait. After first update is completed the second update will be performed.

Comment: It seems solid db has conflicts if I update two view which points to same data.